# "Bean type int could not be found" error, how can I solve it?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I made a TempRequest class and registed as a bean

The code below is TempRequest class.

```
package com.wook.model.dto;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TempRequest {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private String baseDate;
    private String tempKey; 
    
    public TempRequest(int x, int y, String baseDate, String tempKey) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.baseDate = baseDate;
        this.tempKey = tempKey;
    }

    public String getTempKey() {
        return tempKey;
    }

    public void setTempKey(String tempKey) {
        this.tempKey = tempKey;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getBaseDate() {
        return baseDate;
    }

    public void setBaseDate(String baseDate) {
        this.baseDate = baseDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TempRequest [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", baseDate=" + baseDate + ", tempKey=" + tempKey + "]";
    }
    
}
```

To use TempRequest class I Autowired at ReadWeatherController class

ReadWeatherController Class

```
package com.wook.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.wook.model.dto.TempRequest;

@RestController
public class ReadWeatherController {

    private TempRequest tr;

    public ReadWeatherController(TempRequest tr) {
        super();
        this.tr = tr;
    }


    //이제 여기다가 API를 만들면됨
    @GetMapping("/todayMaxMin")
    public String readWeather(
            @RequestParam(value="x")int x,
            @RequestParam(value="y")int y,
            @RequestParam(value="baseDate")String baseDate) {
        
        String tempKey = baseDate+String.valueOf(x)+String.valueOf(y);
        
        tr = new TempRequest(x,y,baseDate,tempKey);
        
        return tr.toString();
    }
    
}
```

And to use these beans I added a packges with using scanBasePackages in main class.
Application Class

```
package com.wook.run;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.wook.controller","com.wook.model","com.wook.service"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

However with this code I get an error like this.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.wook.model.dto.TempRequest required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Spring is trying to create a bean for `TempRequest` (and the only constructor available requires 2 `int`s and 2 `String`s). You actually don't need `TempRequest` as a Spring-managed Bean, so remove `@Component` annotation:

```java
public class TempRequest {
    (...)
}
```

Then you also need to remove `TempRequest` as a property in `ReadWeatherController` because you actually don't need it:

```java
@RestController
public class ReadWeatherController {

    //이제 여기다가 API를 만들면됨
    @GetMapping("/todayMaxMin")
    public String readWeather(
            @RequestParam(value="x") int x,
            @RequestParam(value="y") int y,
            @RequestParam(value="baseDate") String baseDate) {
        
        String tempKey = baseDate+String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y);
        
        TempRequest tr = new TempRequest(x, y, baseDate, tempKey);
        
        return tr.toString();
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, please consider moving your main class `Application` to the package `com.wook` so that you avoid the need of adding all the packages in `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.wook.controller","com.wook.model","com.wook.service"})`:

```java
package com.wook;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a class-level variable `TempRequest tr` in `ReadWeatherController`? As I see no use of it, rather have a method level variable inside the `ReadWeatherController.readWeather()` method.

What's happening is since you have `TempRequest tr` as a parameter in your  `ReadWeatherController` constructor, spring is trying to autowire `TempRequest` and `TempRequest` doesn't have a no-args constructor and the default all args constructor has int and string parameter in it. Since the first param in `TempRequest` constructor is type int and spring can't find bean type of int, spring is throwing `Consider defining a bean of type 'int' in your configuration` error. Change the controller to the following

```java
@RestController
public class ReadWeatherController {


    //이제 여기다가 API를 만들면됨
    @GetMapping("/todayMaxMin")
    public String readWeather(
            @RequestParam(value="x")int x,
            @RequestParam(value="y")int y,
            @RequestParam(value="baseDate")String baseDate) {
        
        String tempKey = baseDate+String.valueOf(x)+String.valueOf(y);
        
        TempRequest tr = new TempRequest(x,y,baseDate,tempKey);
        
        return tr.toString();
    }
    
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `@Component` with a constructor as defined below:

```
@Component
public class TempRequest {
...    
    public TempRequest(int x, int y, String baseDate, String tempKey) {
        ...
    }
```

The error message is saying it can't find beans of type `int` as declared in the component's constructor.

If this TempRequest is intentionally a bean (component) I would suggest refactoring as follows:

```
@Component
public class TempRequest {
    ...    
    public TempRequest(TempRequestConfig trc) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then you can define a `TempRequestConfig` bean:

```
@Component
public class TempRequestConfig {
    public int getX() { ... }
    public int getY() { ... }
    public String getBaseDate() { ... }
    public String getTempKey() { ... }
}
```

This way you can inject the config bean into your temp request bean with Spring's dependency injection.